# Correct way to gracefully exit code prematurely from any section

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bunch of threads, classes, methods, and loops. In each level I currently have to pass, check, and handle a global variable which causes that section of code to exit before completing it's task if the user wants to exit the program early.

Every time-dependent section is literally wrapped in a `if not quit_now():` (or something similar). This cannot be good code-fu - is there a better way?

Comment: If the user wants to exit the program prematurely, can't they send a `SIGINT`/`SIGQUIT` or `SIGTERM` signal to the process? For example, while the process is running, pressing `Ctrl+C` (or your OS's equivalent) will quit the process unless you installed a handler to bypass that behavior.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, but maybe a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) could be useful.

Comment: If you really need section-by-section early termination, I don't know of a fundamentally better way. One small improvement would be to have a global dictionary containing all of the terminate-early variables. That would let you avoid passing them around, but you would still have to check them and handle the early termination. Another optimization would be to put some of your processing in separate processes, then terminate whatever process needs to end early, letting the OS clean up the mess. That works only in some scenarios, of course.